# How can I rewrite multiple recipients to the single one?

Tags: exim

Incoming message have multiple adresses in the `envelope-to` and `to` headers. I want to discard all the original recipients and deliver that message to the special single address if some condition matches in ACL. How that can be done?

Comment: Can you illustrate what you're trying to do with some examples? -- Right now this question sounds like you're looking for the thing. You know, the thing! With the stuff that does the whozits with that other [kajigger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMbCKMgHTa0)!

Comment: So that's a picture: I have a list of regexes to catch sending hosts from dyn-ip networks. All such hosts have to send their mail via their provider's relay. During MAIL stage of smtp session I have $sender_host_name that searches against list mentioned above. If hostname matches, I want to replace all recipients by `honeypot@my.tld`

Comment: You want spam filtering. There are infinitely better ways to do this, like DNS block lists ([zen.spamhaus.org](http://www.spamhaus.org/zen/))

Comment: (note that you don't have to *discard* messages based on a blacklist hit.  You can instruct your MTA to do other things, or call an external script/milter to do the lookup and act accordingly)

Comment: Yes, that's all about spam filtering. Solution is to prepend router, that pipe message to sa-learn, with redirect-router, that replace all recipients with fictitious address honeypot@my.tld

Comment: Also, DNSBLs has no significant effect as far as botnets are smart enough to use correct requisites stolen from infected hosts. Comparable effect can be obtained by simple filtering at CONN and RCPT stages of smtp session. With no DNSBL/greylists only 3-5% of spam reaches my spamd. Now I want to pipe spam to sa-learn instead rejecting it. Without redirect-router message have been piped to sa-learn per each recipient. Now - only once. Case closed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is to classify any email sent to your host *directly from* an IP in a dynamic range as spam, and feed those messages to SpamAssassin so it can learn the characteristics of those spam messages in case they come from "legitimate" servers.

If that is the case what you want to do can be accomplished *without* doing regex matches on the email's headers to isolate senders (computationally expensive!), and *without* rewriting emails (also computationally expensive, adding an extra step), by leveraging DNS blacklists.

1. Check your mail against an appropriate DNS block list
   (The [Spamhaus PBL](http://www.spamhaus.org/pbl/) will have a list of "dyn-ip networks", and it is almost certainly more accurate & less time-consuming than a list you maintain by hand.  Alternatively you could use the [Zen list](http://www.spamhaus.org/zen) and catch lots of other stuff too)
2. If the mail is a hit on the blacklist:

   - Feed it to SpamAssassin (`pipe sa-learn`)
   - Discard the message (`fail` or `finish` it as you desire)

---

I'm not an Exim expert, but from examining the documentation this whole chain can be assembled using [exim filter files](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter_ch03.html) and [a `dnsdb` lookup](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch09.html) (in place of the built-in blacklist support).
If you want to then add your regex matching as additional conditions you can certainly do that as well, but no recipient rewriting appears to be necessary.

Comment: If someone happens to assemble such a filter please post it as an answer - I don't have an exim box around to test with, but I'll happily upvote a working solution that's more than just my algorithmic outline

Comment: can I post my currenf config as answer to my own question? I'm not familiar enough with serverfault and don't know local rules in depth.